# R: reading in a .csv turns all "" (blank spaces) to NA

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, read.csv

I have a data set in which I converted all "~" values to blank spaces "", and when I use the View() function to view the data set, I can clearly see the blank spaces. However, after I save my modified data frame as a .csv file via write.csv and read it again in R via read.csv, all the blank spaces are somehow changed to NA values. I tried to change all my NA values back to the blank spaces again, but the same problem occurs when I save as csv and read it again.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: would you please post sample data and code that reproduces the problem? the answer probably has to do with your `na.strings` in `read.csv` or your `na` in `write.csv`, or possibly whether the values are characters or factors, but there's no way to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is the parameter `na` you can specify

```
write.csv(data, "data.csv", row.names=FALSE, na="")
```

When you read it again you need to convert NA to blank everytime though

```
data[is.na(data)]<-""
```

Comment: what's weird is in a different column, the blank spaces are appearing perfectly fine